How to turn off linting in ipynb notebooks?
Is it possible to turn off the squiggly underline linting in notebooks but not other (Python) scripts?

You could add the following codes to your settings.json if you want to ignore the warnings and errors of Pylance without disabling the other features provided by the language server:
"python.analysis.ignore": [
        "*"
    ]

